# What is the most advanced and reliable COMET solution today?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, scalability, comet

**Problem**: need to serve millions of realtime notifications to web users per day.

Requirements:

- Scalability
- Cross-domain requests without proxies. (XHR polling won't work)
- Cross browser support. (Can't rely only on websockets or flash sockets)
- Well-tested and maintained components

So far I have come up with some solutions wich have various limitations:

**RabbitMQ + node.js + Socket.IO**

This is my favorite solution so far but there were complains about reliability of node.js part, when it comes to huge number of requests. Experience of plurk.com http://amix.dk/blog/post/19577

**XMPP/BOSH + strophe.js**

This also looks reliable but due to limitation of BOSH, JSONP polling is not possible and therefore - no cross-domain requests.

**Mochiweb + Dojo**

It is claimed that Facebook uses Mochiweb for their chat system (which sucks btw). Seems too complex to setup and maintain. Am I wrong?

**JBoss Netty**

Java server. This is what plurk.com uses to serve their notifications. It is unclear of what can be used on browser side.

**Faye + node.js**

Very easy to set up, but seems that it doesn't work well on heavy loads, not tested and there's no clear way to scale.

Any ideas or experience? :)